# Android TextView display wrong style on my API19 devices

Tags: android, textview, android-theme

This is run on my device Sony Xperia Z `API 19`

[image]

However, this should be the result for `API 19`

what happen to my `TextView` ??? Please help.

[image]

**UPDATE Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.app.sml"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
              android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
                android:name="MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: i think this is due to various sdk version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare a theme for your application, so the default device theme is used.
If you want to use holo theme (which apparently you do) you should specifically declare it. Just add this attribute under application (or a specific activity):

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    ...>
```

The entire Holo theme family (Theme.Holo, Theme.Holo.Light, Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar) is available for any device with sdk level >= 14. Just choose the one you want.